# TweenMax to Universal Tween Engine porting bug

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation, android-animation

I have the following AS3 code

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < _triangles.length; i++) 
    {
        var t:Triangle = _triangles[i] as Triangle;
        // ... calculate for d and x based on the pos of the triangle and random()
        TweenMax.to(t, 10, { alpha:x, delay:d, ease:Cubic.easeOut } );
    }
```

At iteration no. 241, for example, `TweenMax.getTweensOf(_triangles).length` gives a value of 241 while `TweenMax.getTweensOf(t).length` is 1.

In Java this would be

```
for (Triangle t : _triangles) {
    // ... calculate for d and x based on the pos of the triangle and random()
    Tween.to(t, TriangleAccessor.ALPHA, 10f).delay(d).ease(Cubic.OUT).target(x).start(tweenManager);
}
```

where `tweenManager.getObjects().size()` gives 241, just like in case of AS3, but the resulting animation is completely different: the Java app shows all animations nearly at the same time and at random positions, while the AS3 code shows it gradually expanding from the center of the screen to all directions.  Any ideas how to reproduce the AS3 behavior in Java?

*Update:*

I'm gonna go ahead and implement it with the animation API in Android >=11 just to see if just me or there's a bug in the tween library. But making it work with lower Android versions would still be nice.

Comment: ping to @aurelien-ribon, the author of the Java lib

Comment: In AS3 the tween is indeed being applied to each individual element. I suppose when you pass an array to `getTweensOf` it just checks each item in the array.

Comment: So basically the problem is the animations are different?

Comment: `.delay(d)` is not handled correctly in the Java library (just in case, my project setup is here: https://github.com/ber4444/universal-tween-engine/tree/master/java/android/surfaceview-animation) -- tweens get queued up and then they are drawn all at once, so that a long delay (sum of all delays specified in the loop) is applied at the beginning of simultaneous animations rather than to each individual animations

Comment: For a test, I created a new thread for each `Tween.to()` but that does not solve the problem... again clueless! (btw, the author says that "everything should run in the same thread" -- http://www.aurelienribon.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=664&sid=bf052987af790288645db50dd23918b3 -- which made all animations parallel, rather than the "wave" effect that I'm looking for)

Comment: Are you sure the delay is different in every tween?

Comment: Yes, I just edited my question to make that clear. IT should create a wave effect with the delay smallest in the center and increasing towards the edges.